# Is possible to use query builder in form, filtering by other table/field value?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have two entities: `A` and `B`. These entities have a unidirectional relationship. In particular external key is into `B` entity and, based on the cardinality of relationship, `A` hasn't any "direct" attribute (property) for retrieve `B` objects.

Ok, now let's say I want to build a form for some `B` objects.

In my FormType I will do something like:

```
public function BuildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder)
{
  [...]
  $builder->add('A',entity,array('class'=>'MyFooBundle:A'));
  [...]
}
```

Ok, now let's say I want to apply a "filter" upon `A` dropdown list and this filter is particular: I don't want to show any `A` entity that has already a relationship with `B`.

To me this is very tricky to reach as I know that I can use a closure and `query_builder` option but the problem is that `query_builder`, as far as I know, use class of the field to do the query. What I've tried is something like

```
$sub_query = $repo->createQueryBuilder('B');
$sub_query = $sub_query->select('B.A')
               ->from('MyFooBundle:B','b');

$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('A');

return $qb->where($qb->expr()->notIn('A.id', $sub_query->getDQL()));
```

Of course `B.A` returns the corrispective of `A.id` (foreign key contained in B)

However `$sub_query` still try to use even `A` into that select (as class of attribute where `query_builder` is applied is `A`)

So, coming to real question, is there an equivalent method for do what I need or "simply" have I to make this relationship bi-directional and use directly attribute included into `A` class?

Hope is clear

Comment: I would definitely make this relationship bi-directional. Why is it a problem to do so ?

Comment: No problems indeed. I started with unidirectional and I can switch easily to bi-directional. I was only asking if could be done without: could be any case where you can't switch to different structure and you need to use this kind of scenario?

Comment: Is the type of relationship OneToMany (each B can have many A)? If yes, how come it's possible to have A.id(s) which has not B.id? Or maybe it's in reverse then I have one solution

Comment: One more, is it `nullable=true` or it's required that each B has one A and each A has one B?

Comment: @DonCallisto hopefully my answer be close to what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the type of relationship which is OneToOne and A side is nullable, you can make a DQL as:

```
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('A')
   ->leftJoin('YourBundle:BEntity', 'B', 'WITH', 'A.id = B.A_id')
   ->where('B.id IS NULL')
   ->getQuery();
$result = $qb->getResult();
```

The created DQL means, select all A records join with B where the B.id does not exist in A

Comment: Now i modified it for a bi-directional, when I have free time I'll verify this solution. For the moment, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, this is a working solution (just tested). By the way could you modify your answer as external key is into "B" entity and not into "A"?. That way will be better and a full-working answer, otherwise some users could try and find that doesn't works.

Comment: Nice to hear it; sure I did; I did not know about the A and B structure that's why

Comment: No problem, this answer should help some people that could fall into this situation :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my example, hope that will help.

```
$builder->add("parent", 'entity', $this->getParentUserEntityOptions());

private function getParentUserEntityOptions() {
    return array('empty_value' => 'Select',
        'class' => 'TMSolution\UserBundle\Entity\User',
        'property' => 'username',
        'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er ) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
                    ->where('u.locked = 0');
    });
}
```

Comment: How this could possibly help me? I know how to use/create a query builder :)

Comment: are u ? - 
// Example - $qb->expr()->notIn('u.id', '2')
    public function notIn($x, $y); // Returns Expr\Func instance